# Remove duplicate entry in dynamically added row with jQuery autocomplete in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am working with a form that append row and autocomplete script using jQuery. They works fine but how can I remove the duplicate entry? or perhaps remove the entry which already been selected in the drop down options?

[image]

**here's my function for autocomplete**

```
public function salesResponse(Request $request){
    $query = $request->get('term','');
    $wh2Summaries=Warehouse2StockSummaries::with('product');

    if($request->type == 'product_code'){
        $wh2Summaries->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('product_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        }); 
    }

    if($request->type=='product_name'){
        $wh2Summaries->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('product_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        }); 
    }

    if($request->type=='product_id'){
        $wh2Summaries->whereHas('product', function ($q) use ($query) {
            $q->where('product_code', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%');
        }); 
    }

    $wh2Summaries=$wh2Summaries->get();        
    $data=array();
    foreach ($wh2Summaries as $wh2Summary) {
        $data[]=array(
            'product_code'=>$wh2Summary->product->product_code,
            'name'=>$wh2Summary->product->name,
            'price'=>$wh2Summary->product->price,
            'quantity'=>$wh2Summary->qty_in-$wh2Summary->qty_out,
            'id'=>$wh2Summary->product->id
        );
    }
    if(count($data))
        return $data;
    else
        return [
            'product_code'=>'No product',
            'name'=>'',
            'price'=>'',
            'qty_out'=>'',
            'id'=>''
        ];
}
```

**and here's my AutoComplete script**

```
//autocomplete script
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
  type = $(this).data('type');

  if(type =='product_code' )autoType='product_code'; 
  if(type =='product_name' )autoType='name'; 
  if(type =='product_price' )autoType='price'; 
  if(type =='quantity' )autoType='quantity'; 
  if(type =='product_id' )autoType='id'; 

   $(this).autocomplete({
       minLength: 0,
       source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('searchaSaleItems') }}",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term : request.term,
                    type : type,
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var array = $.map(data, function (item) {
                       return {
                           label: item[autoType],
                           value: item[autoType],
                           data : item
                       }
                    });
                    response(array)
                }
            });
       },
       select: function( event, ui ) {
           var data = ui.item.data;
           var limit
           id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
           id = id_arr.split("_");
           elementId = id[id.length-1];
           $('#product_code_'+elementId).val(data.product_code);
           $('#product_name_'+elementId).val(data.name);
           $('#product_price_'+elementId).val(data.price).prop('min', data.price);
           $('#product_id_'+elementId).val(data.id);
           $('#quantity_'+elementId).prop('max', data.quantity);
           $('#quantity_warning_'+elementId).text('You have '+data.quantity-data.quantity+' in your stocks');
       }
   });
});
```

in my current code I can't control the limit of the stocks because the duplicate entries. Please help me and thank you so much in advance!

**Update**
add my append script

```
  var rowCount = 1;

  $('#add').click(function() {
    rowCount++;
    $('#orders').append(<tr id="row'+rowCount+'"><td> . ... ....</td></tr> );
});
```

Comment: which duplicate entry?

Comment: Hi @Flame like for example in my screenshot. the DWN is entered trice already. My question is how am I going to prevent that from happening? Thanks!

Comment: I think the way to go is to select your form rows with jQuery, and add their product codes to an array. Then filter your select list based upon that. Something like `var arr = []; $('input[name="product_code"]').each(function() {arr.push($(this).val());});`

Comment: ahhh that make  sense @Flame Thanks I'll try it now

Comment: i can't make it work I put this,             $('#product_code_'+elementId).each(function() {
              arr.push($(this).val(data.product_code));
            }); inside the  select: function( event, ui )